# for loop in list of URL's

Tags: python-3.x

i want to use a certain URL & branch_location & then loop thru my code
and then grab the next URL & branch_location & then loop thru my code
and then grab etc... i have about 50 locations, how can i do this in python 3.62. thank you.

```
use_url = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/forecast10day/q/il/chicago.json"
branch_location = 'chicago, il'

use_url = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/forecast10day/q/ca/los angeles.json"
branch_location = 'los angeles, ca'


# code to loop thru is below
url = use_url
req = urllib.request.Request(
    url, 
    data=None, 
    headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
    }
)
f = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
json_string = f.read()
parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
etc...
```

Comment: Define a `dict` of `{<branch_location>: <use_url>` and then use a `for` loop, e.g. `for branch_location, use_url in branch_dict.items():`

Comment: how do i create a dictionary with multiple items? i tried:  dict = {'use_url': 'http://www.example.com', 'branch_location': 'chicago'}
but i now want to add a 2nd entry with www.example2.com and new york

Comment: Don't use the labels, `branch_dict = {'chicago': 'example.com', 'new york': 'www.example2.com', ...}` then iterator over this dictionary `for branch_location, use_url in branch_dict.items():`

Comment: i tried this and it is not working. i am close, but not quite there.

branch_dict = {
        'Atlanta, GA': 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/a17549bfda81239f/forecast10day/q/ga/atlanta.json',
        'Austin, TX': 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/a17549bfda81239f/forecast10day/q/tx/austin.json'}

for branch_location, use_url in branch_dict.items():
    print(branch_dict[branch_location])
    print(branch_dict[use_url]);

Comment: Just `print(branch_location)` the values have already been assigned.

Comment: but i want to be able to pull up one variable:  chicago
and then pull up another variable for chicago:  example.com
then loop thru that and 
but i want to be able to pull up one variable:  atlanta
and then pull up another variable for chicago:  example2.com
, how do i do that with dictionary?

Comment: Loop through what, you haven't provided enough information. `print(use_url)` will print the appropriate url for the branch in the loop.